# How many timeouts should be replaced with an interval?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given I have a dataset `objects` that contains many entries/objects, wherein each entry has its own DateTime property, I was wondering if should (A) simply run a `setTimeout` for each object or (B) one `setInterval` that fires events based on the time has passed when I want to fire a specific `EventToCall`?

Minimum time from now: 1 day

Maximum time form now: 10 days

I expect to have ~1000 objects each with a different DateTime. Also note: `EventToCall` will make an SQL query.

(A)

```
objects.forEach((v) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
   v.EventToCall();
 }, (v.dateTime - new Date());
});
```

(B),e.g. using [easytimer](https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/) or [EventDispatcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/EventDispatcher) or `setInterval`

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.start();
var funcsToCall = new Map(); // Maps <DateTimeWhenToFire, Function>

timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    funcsToCall.forEach((v, k) => {
         if (k < new Date()) {
             v();
         }
    });
});
```

Am I overthinking this or what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Just use `setTimeout()`, it's much less verbose and you don't have to worry about removing the interval.

Comment: Your question is opinion-based, and may be off-topic for Stackoverflow. But here is my take: `setTimeout/Interval` is not precise, especially when the trigger delay is a long time from now. It will tend to drift. And having thousands of them running at the same time won't help. Running a single `setInterval` on a short delay (every 1 sec for example), checking what time it is, and finding the corresponding handlers to call will be more precise (home-made, or using a library)